# Get unicode script from a rune in Go

Tags: go, unicode

In Unicode there are some existing defined range [unicode range](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Spring_2003/ling538/UnicodeRanges.html), I'm looking for something so that given a `rune` I can find its [Unicode Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_(Unicode)).

In the `unicode` package I found this [function](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#In), but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

```
chineseChars := "人人"
for _, rune := range chineseChars {
    fmt.Println(unicode.In(rune, unicode.Bopomofo))
}
```

This piece of code prints `false` when it should print `true`

Comment: @CeriseLimón: why don't you post it as an answer the OP could accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unicode package puts `人` in [Han](https://godoc.org/unicode#Han), not [Bopomofo](https://godoc.org/unicode#Bopomofo). The expression `unicode.In('人', unicode.Han)` evaluates to `true`.